# Display spinning wheel/circle image on browser during long running operation

Tags: plotly-dash

When a `button` is clicked on a `dash` layout form, the `browser` tab (in `Chrome` anyway) says "Updating". I would like to give more obvious feedback that the operation is running.

**What is the canonical way to display a spinning wheel image during a long running calculation in a dash callback?**

```
# This is a long running operation
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('datatable-optionchain','children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('button', 'n_clicks')],
    #[dash.dependencies.State('input-box', 'value')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('dropdown1', 'value'),
    dash.dependencies.State('my-date-picker-single', 'date'),
    dash.dependencies.State('dropdown2', 'value')],
    )
def update_output(n_clicks, svalue, dtvalue, tvalue):
    #How do I put a spinning wheel here to advise user we are working on it?
```

Comment: Dash loading states: https://dash.plotly.com/loading-states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped quite a bit. I can't get the spinning wheel to work, but I did get the `.css` version to work. albeit with some inconsistencies:

https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-loading-states/5687/36